# how to create unclickabale screen on the click on the button using CSS

Tags: css

I want to make a screen unclickable by spreading a think transparent layer of any color over the screen on the click event of a button using CSS. 
Please help with this.

Comment: What? You want a what? Where is your code?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks He wants a thick transparent layer of any color over the screen ;)

Comment: @levib, I forgot about the thickness attribute, is that measured in pixels? And does it affect the mass or density of the div?

Comment: @jcolicchio Given that he wants to spread it across the screen I am not quite sure if it has an even thickness. Possibly more of a peanut-butter type scenario. A transparent colored peanut butter.

Comment: Funny guys, remember theeself when started

Comment: I'm thinkin `.spread { color: transparent; thickness: peanutbutter chunky; }` should do the trick. Also dmi3y, you have a fair point. I remember my first attempts at English =)

Comment: @jcolicchio nice shoot) meant CSS, but yet. I am from mobile, could someone edit?

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery and CSS, you could define a class .spread :

```
.spread {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

And when you click on the button:

```
$('body').append("<div class='spread'></div>");
```

This would add the div to the body, and the div would position itself in the top left corner. You may also have to put:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/TuP2A/

Answer (score 0):

It should be super easy

HTML

```
<body>
   some code here
   <div class=overlay><div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
   z-index:100;
   top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
}
```